# Re-using random string generated by PHP function

Tags: php, string, random

I'm using the following code to generate a random string:

```
<?php
function random_string( )
{
$character_set_array = array( );
$character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 5, 'characters' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' );
$character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 1, 'characters' => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' );
$character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 1, 'characters' => '0123456789' );
$character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 1, 'characters' => '!@#$+-*&?:' );
$temp_array = array( );
foreach ( $character_set_array as $character_set )
{
for ( $i = 0; $i < $character_set[ 'count' ]; $i++ )
{
$temp_array[ ] = $character_set[ 'characters' ][ rand( 0, strlen( $character_set[ 'characters' ] ) - 1 ) ];
}
}
shuffle( $temp_array );
return implode( '', $temp_array );
}
?>



<?php echo random_string(); ?>
```

My question is - hopefully! - a simple one...

I'd like to re-use this random string elsewhere, say by calling $reuseablestring. Is this possible?

(To explain why I need to do this, I'm building a digital delivery system. The random string will be saved to a database and then passed, as a hidden form field to Google Checkout. Google then provides a link to the download page, with the random string attached. Once that page has been accessed, the status of the random string is changed to 'used' in the database, which will prevent the file being downloaded a second time).

Many, many thanks for your help. I **really** appreciate it!

Best wishes,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the return value of random_string() to a variable that you than can use in your script.
`$reuseablestring = random_string();`

Comment: It's never that easy is it Björn?! Oh, it is! Thank you so much for your help - I'm really grateful!